# "Unknown "link_attributes" filter."

Tags: drupal, twig, ddev

So I'm trying to setup a local environment with ddev for the first time. I got it running, cloned my live files with git and imported my DB.

Site ain't working and got this in the log :

> Uncaught PHP Exception Twig\Error\SyntaxError: "Unknown
>   "link_attributes" filter." at
>   /var/www/html/web/themes/customs/myTheme/templates/menu--main.html.twig

Any pointer how to fix that ? I did :

```
ddev exec drush en link_attributes
```

Which outputs

> [notice] Already enabled: link_attributes

Comment: I don't think this is a probably a ddev issue. It's much more likely an issue with your code. I assume you've rebuilt the cache?

Comment: Yeah I rebuilt cache. It's just that the site is working on the 2 VPS I tried... I don't know where to look :/

Comment: You might try this in Drupal Answers. Totally weird that this is after importing a working db. Was the db you imported working with this exact code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that it's from the module twig_link_attributes, not link_attributes... When I saw the error and scrolled through the module list, I looked into link_attributes to make sure it was downloaded and enabled. It's the wrong one.

My twig_link_attributes folder is empty cause it's a git submodule and it didn't download. Gonna fix that and I should be good. Damn filter named the same as another module D: